# Dot product filtered dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter

Let's assume I have two pandas dataframe like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Component': ['A','B','C','D'],'Theme': ['T1','T2','T3','T3'],'Weights': [0.5,0.1,0.1,0.3]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [-0.1,0.05,-0.07,-0.5,0.02],'B': [-0.3,0.02,-0.01,-0.4,0.01],'C': [-0.8,0.00,-0.01,-0.1,0.07],'D': [-0.08,0.1,-0.01,-0.05,0.03],},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4])
```

I am looking for a "smart way" to compute the "sumproduct" (or dot product) of the two dataframe grouped by theme. The thing is that "theme" is missing in the second dataframe and the only way to link the two dataframes is by Component.

Let's do an example:
For the Theme T3, the result should be a dataframe like this:

```
df3=pd.DataFrame({'T3':[-0.104,0.03,-0.004,-0.025,0.016]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4])
```

Details of the computation are as follows (sumproduct of df1 (filtered by theme T3) and df2:

```
0.1*-0.8+0.3*-0.08 = -0.104

0.1*0+0.3*0.1=0.03

0.1*-0.01+0.3*-0.01=-0.004

0.1*-0.1+0.3*-0.05=-0.025

0.1*0.07+0.3*0.03=0.016
```

If we convert df1 and df2 in two numpy arrays, we can do the dot product of the tranpose(df1) and transpose(df2). That would work perfectly. However, since I need to filter per theme, I am kind of stuck.

Overall I would like to have 3 dataframes (because I have 3 themes)

Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the same index on both sides, it is requirement of the `dot` product:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Component')
```

Apply the desired filter criteria with `where`, then fill the NA values with 0:

```
df2.dot(df1.where(df1.Theme=='T3').Weights.fillna(0))

0   -0.104
1    0.030
2   -0.004
3   -0.025
4    0.016
dtype: float64
```